# Spring i18n question mark instead of text

Tags: spring, internationalization

I hava i18n, but experience problems with chinese and hindi letters. I have question marks ????? instead of text.

Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">

    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" /> 
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />               
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
</bean>  

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />

</bean> 

<mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:interceptor>
         <mvc:mapping path="/**" />     

    <bean class="com.aartek.interceptor.LoginInterceptor" />                
    </mvc:interceptor>

    <mvc:interceptor>
         <mvc:mapping path="/**" /> 

    <bean class="com.aartek.interceptor.SecondInterceptor" />           
    </mvc:interceptor>

    <mvc:interceptor>
         <mvc:mapping path="/product.do*" />    

    <bean class="com.aartek.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor" />          
    </mvc:interceptor>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

</mvc:interceptors>
```

Login.jsp

```
   <%@page  contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" 
   language="java"  %>

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
   <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

   <html>

     <head>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>

    <span style="float: right">

   <a href="?lang=en">English</a> |<a href="?lang=fr">French</a>|<a href="? 
              lang=hi_IN">Hindi</a>|<a href="?lang=zh_CN">Chinese</a>

    </span>

     <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="keyUser" 
         action="checkLogin.do">
     <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="label.userId"  
                         /></td>

                <td><form:input path="userId" id="userId" /></td>


            </tr>
```

In similar way I wrote for email id,password and submit.

3.messages_zh_CN.properties

```
   label.userId=\u7528\u6237\u540D
   label.emailId=\u7535\u5B50\u90AE\u4EF6ID
   label.password=\u5BC6\u7801
   label.submit=\u63D0\u4EA4
```

In similar way I wrote for English, Hindi and French .

My question:
How I can remove the question marks and its for Chinese and Hindi only, how can I display correct text?

Comment: what's the file encode of your properites file?

Answer (score 0):

File encode of your properites file, java class, jsp should be UTF-8.